# Best method for rendering collection in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm using Backbone and I have the following model and collection

```
App.Models.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

App.Collections.People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Person,
    url: 'api/people',
});
```

However what I'm struggling on is the best way to render this collection.  Here's how I've done it so far which works but doesn't seem to be the most elegant solution

```
App.Views.PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".people"),

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new App.Collections.People();

        //This seems like a bad way to do it?
        var that = this;
        this.collection.fetch({success: function(){
            that.render();
        }});
    },

    render: function () {
        var that = this;
        _.each(this.collection.models, function (item) {
            that.renderPerson(item);
        }, this);
    },
```

I'm fairly new to Backbone but have to assign `this` to a different variable to I use it inside of the success function just seems like a bad way of doing things?  Any help on best practices would be appreciated.

Comment: you make it more complicated than needed since your callback doesn't drill a sub-prop or do anything conditional, so you can just say `_.each(this.collection.models, this.renderPerson, this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone allows you to register for events that you can react to.  When the collection is synchronized with the server, it will always fire the `sync` event.  You can choose to listen for that event and call any given method.  For instance ...

```
initialize: function () {
    this.collection = new App.Collections.People();
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "sync", this.render);

    // Fetch the initial state of the collection
    this.collection.fetch();
}
```

... will set up your collection so that it would always call `this.render()` whenever `sync` occurs.

[The docs on Backbone Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) are succinct but pretty good.  Keep in mind a few things:

- The method you use to register event listeners (i.e. `listenTo` or `on`) changes how you provide the context of the called function.  `listenTo`, for instance, will use the current context automatically; `on` will not.  [This piece of the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this) explains it pretty well.
- If you need to remove a view, you will need to disconnect event listeners.  The easiest way to do that is to use `listenTo` to connect them in the first place; then when destroying the view you can just call `view.stopListening()`.

For rendering, there are a lots of suggestions for how to do it.  Generally having a view to render each individual model is one way.  You can also use `Backbone.Collection#each` to iterate over the models *and* control the scope of the iterating function.  For instance:

```
render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(model) {
        var view = new App.Collections.PersonView({ model: model });
        view.render();
        this.$el.append(view.$el);
    }, this);    
}
```

Note the second argument to `.each` specifies the scope of the iterator.  (Again, have a look at [the docs on controlling scope](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this).  If you'd rather have a framework help out with the rendering, check out Marionette's [CollectionView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md) and [ItemView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, although when I add `this.listenTo(this.collection, "sync", this.render);` my render function wasn't called.  I had to call the fetch method first

Comment: Ah -- sorry for not clarifying that!  The "sync" event is fired whenever the Collection is synchronized with the server.  That will happen whenever the `fetch()` completes asynchronously, so you do have to call fetch explicitly.  If this answer is good enough, please consider accepting it.  Have fun!

Comment: Edited the answer to include the `fetch()` call.

Answer (score 0):

If your view is supposed to just render the collection you can send the collection to temnplate and iterate through in template, otherwise you can create another subView for that purpose or send the individual models of the collection to another subview and append to the container, hope it was helpful.